# Laravel How to store payment gateway response url data value in database

Tags: php, laravel-5, payment-gateway

Currently, i'm integrating a new payment gateway in laravel. 
In response url, I am getting a datastring from the payment gateway like:

```
http://www.example.com/payment/response?txn_status=00&txn_msg=success&txn_err_msg=NA&clnt_txn_ref=000000&tpsl_txn_id=000000&txn_amt=1.00&hash=0000000000000000000
```

I want to store the url datastring value into a database
How should I able to do it in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

As url string contains the get parameters, so your route will be 'get'. Then you have to write this:

```
$GetData = Input::get();

//To print
echo "<pre>";
print_r($GetData);

//To log the response
Log::info("Payment response : ".print_r($GetData, true));
```

Now, to insert this response, use laravel eloquent or the simple query.